# A thread asking a grammatical question has been closed twice

Tags: discussion

I think this thread should be re-opened:

- [The use of nominative "whom"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181992/you-owe-a-duty-to-persons-whom-it-is-foreseeable-are-likely-to-be-harmed-why)

The "duplicate thread" doesn't seem to have an answer to the OP's question.

I think that "closed" thread poses an example that is grammatically interesting, and maybe not so easy to explain.

I've already voted for it to be re-opened, so that ELU members who are interested in English grammar can try to answer the OP's question.

Comment: @F.E. +1. I thank you effusively for your support.

Comment: Rolling back all the transformations is not that difficult, and that shows why _whom_ is grammatically incorrect. Don't be surprised, btw -- lawyers don't study grammar in law school. They learn to cite and quote and not to criticize the judge's grammar.

Comment: @JohnLawler Google books: try "whom we suspect are" versus "who we suspect are" (845 v 460) - small minority are partitive, very few are law. A general Google of same terms: 1,550, 000 v 54, 600- staggering. If the rule doesn't describe what people do, then ... Ngram won't even appear for the former but gives small figures for the latter (may all be partitive - who knows). Shakespeare, Dickens, Samuel Butler and many more have all used *whom* for subjects extracted from complement clauses embedded within  RCs. ...

Comment: @Araucaria: _Suspect_ has nothing to do with _whom_ usage; it's just one verb of thousands that can take a complement clause. If you're talking about the common usage of "whom" to [make a sentence sound more formal](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html), are you suggesting that that is the new standard and therefore the old rule is in abeyance? You may be correct, which is why I always recommend that no one ever use _whom_ at all, and therefore avoid such constructions in the first place.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't disagree with you about *suspect* and *whom* in particular. However, you seem to imply that everyone writing anything that ends up on Google is trying to sound more formal when they use certain verbs like "suspect" - not entirely convincing, might be considered a rather under-substantiated conjecture.  You don't comment on the Shakespeare or Dickens btw. The main points I want to make here are grammatical and are in the next comment ...

Comment: @JohnLawler More importantly, as I commented and Janus posted, this 'nominative' pronoun can be omitted (without auxiliary be), which does not fit with nominative *who*. Lastly, in several languages the extracted pronoun in these situations appears to take the case that a pronoun would if it occurred alone at the original site without the rest of the relative clause. This doesn't appear, after some admittedly cursory investigation, and according to Janus' comments, to be optional. In English there's no way to tell, because *who* readily occurs as either subj or obj ... (grossly oversimplified)

Comment: It depends on what structure is being accessed. There are two stacked subject clauses, paraphraseable as _You owe a duty to [`the-people` (such) [that [for `the-people` to be harmed] is likely] is foreseeable]_. You can extract the relative pronoun from the subject of the infinitive clause, or from the subject of the tensed clause, depending on what intermediate transformations are performed. Since nobody usually keeps track of those, one winds up with a questionable structure no matter which one is picked. So, I repeat, don't use _whom_.

Comment: @JohnLawler That comment would be useful posted at the OP's original page. There are simpler, non-extraposition structures which may follow the pattern described above: eg *We don't like the people whom we have long suspected ___ are eating all the pies*. Re the advice, not useful for analysis alone - but (imo) very, very good advice!!

Comment: Yes, well, I missed the original and it's closed and I've posted it here. If that makes it hard to find, that's the breaks. There's certainly no way to make it **easy** to find.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks to F.E., yourself and others, the post is now open!

Answer (score 1):

I can be pretty ruthless about closing duplicates, but I think this question should be reopened. The "he/who, him/whom" rule ultimately provides the answer here, but the sentence being analyzed in the newer question is a convoluted one, and requires some untangling before it's clear how the rule should be applied.

The rule I try to follow when closing as duplicate is "Will the person asking this question receive a *full* and *useful* answer over at the other question?" Here, the asker explicitly stated that they consulted the other question first and that it didn't provide a satisfactory answer, and it's not hard for me to see why that would be the case. Remember, [duplication is not necessarily bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/):

> Quite the contrary — some duplication is desirable. There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find the answer they’re looking for. And isn’t that, really, the whole point of this exercise?

Comment: +1. I thank you effusively for your support.